# Table is not being created automatically in Database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, xml, hibernate

I have been trying to get my Java application with Hibernate to connect to MySQL database in localhost:3306 and create a table, but it's not happening. it gives error. But the same code works when i create a table beforehand by the given name and then run the app, it inserts all data in the table accordingly.

In hibernate.cfg.xml file i have tried to set my
"update" to both update and create. None of it works when there is no table called "Employee" in the database.

As per my understanding when this option is set to "Update", it creates a table and inserts the data (when the table doesn't exist and it just inserts the data when the table already exists.

The error is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'type=MyISAM' at line 1

To solve this is have tried all :
MySQL55Dialect
MySQL57Dialect
MySQL57InnoDBDialect
MySQL5Dialect
MySQL8Dialect
MySQLDialect
MySQLInnoDBDialect
MySQLISAMDialect

But it doesn't work

Here are my codes:
[EMployee.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXBAo.png)

[App.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6gHE.png)

[hibernate.cfg.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oU2vO.png)

[pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aSUH.png)

Comment: Show us the SQL code that has the syntax problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.